# Am working on a timer, Why is the breakCount() function not updating after using setTimeout()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the breakCount function to start counting when the previous session times out, it only updates the variable $breakData but doesn't countdown, why? how can I make it work? If this snippet doesn't help you understand what I mean please say so.

```js
function holdCount() {
  var t,
    secs = 60,
    mins = countSession.innerHTML;
  mins--;

  function countdown() {
    secs--;
    if (secs < 0) {
      mins--;
      secs = 59;
    };
    if (secs < 10) {
      countSession.innerHTML = mins + ':' + '0' + secs;
    } else {
      countSession.innerHTML = mins + ':' + secs;
    };
    t = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);

    if (mins == 0 && secs == 0) {
      clearTimeout(t);
      breakCount();

      function breakCount() {
        var $breakData = $('#displayBreak').text();
        $breakData--;
        $('#sessionCount').text($breakData);
      }
      setTimeout(breakCount, 1000);
    }
  }
  countdown();
}

countSession.addEventListener('click', holdCount, false);
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bx4dms3f/1/ - works fine

Comment: Any error in your browser console

Comment: Arun P Johny,  can you take time out to view my JS fiddle to see what exactly am trying to do?

Comment: where is your jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lumexralph/wtwgpmpg/......this is my fiddle Arun P Johny

Comment: now what is suppose to happen?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wtwgpmpg/1/ - You didn't include jQuery library in the fiddle even though you are using it in your code

Comment: When you click on the last div it should start countdown and when it reaches 0 it should start countdown of 10 in the first div.....

Comment: I have updated the fiddle check it now....https://jsfiddle.net/Lumexralph/wtwgpmpg/4/, if you click the timer div, it should start a countdown on the sessiondata = 25 and when done it should start a countdown of breakdata = 10 in the timer div...that's all